# Converting a input (Password) into MD5

Tags: python, md5

Hi I'm a bit new to this and can't exactly figure out how to get it working.

Here is my current code:

```
import hashlib

def PasswordCreate():
    password = input(str("Please enter a password next to this text"))
    password = hashlib.md5()
    password.update(password.encode('utf-8'))
    return password.hexdigest()

PasswordCreate()
```

The error is:

```
AttributeError: '_hashlib.HASH' object has no attribute 'encode'
```

Comment: So, what is your _exact_ problem?

Comment: @yeputons The code doesn't work, I will edit and put the error in the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import hashlib

def PasswordCreate():
    user_in = input(str("Please enter a password next to this text"))
    password = hashlib.md5()
    password.update(user_in.encode("utf-8"))
    return password.hexdigest()

PasswordCreate()
```

Just an issue in your variables. See `user_in` in my code

Comment: Thanks the code runs fine now, but it doesn't appear to output the string ( I would like to do this for testing) How can I achieve this?

Comment: Just encapsulate the `PasswordCreate()` in a `print()` function, ie. `print(PasswordCreate())`

Comment: I just want to make something clear, too. You have not employed salting with your code, would highly recommend this if security is important. Wikipedia sometimes has great explanations :) https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Salt_(cryptography)

Comment: Hey, just wondering if you could hit the accepted answer button? It'd be much appreciated :)

Comment: Hi, sorry for not accepting, and it worked thanks, and no security is not important for me, this is a side project

Answer (score 1):

**Hello Josh,**

Try this code,

```
import hashlib
def PasswordCreate():
  inputVar = input(str("Please enter a password next to this text: "))
  password = hashlib.md5()
  password.update(inputVar.encode("utf-8"))
  return password.hexdigest()

# Create Variable for dipslay encoded value.
displayPass = PasswordCreate()
print "User Password is: ",displayPass
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps something like following:

```
import hashlib

def PasswordCreate():
    password = raw_input(str("Please enter a password next to this text: "))
    return hashlib.md5(password).hexdigest()

PasswordCreate()
```

Comment: I am using Python 3.5, raw_input is not a thing i'm pretty sure (at least it doesn't work)

Comment: Also in python 3.5 you have to encode the 'thing' so this is doesn't really help

Answer (score 0):

As simple as I can put:

```
import hashlib
print(hashlib.md5(input().encode()).hexdigest())
```